# Compressed SWF format not supported

Tags: ffmpeg, flash, flv

When trying to convert a .swf file to .flv in ffmpeg, I get this error. Is there any way to decompress or bypass this error in ffmpeg, or is there any other command line video conversion tool that can do this conversion for me with a compressed .swf?

Comment: does your swf have any actionscript code in it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are conversion tools, and one comes with ffmpeg actually. It's called cws2fws. You can find the source file at "ffmpeg_root/tools/cws2fws.c". I'm not sure if you need to pass additional options to your ./configure script to make it compile.